# Помогите найти ошибку в коде, перевод числа из любой сс в любую

Tags: c, строки, рекурсия

Условие задачи такое: Перевести число из системы счисления с основанием b1 в систему с основанием b2 (b1 и b2 больше 2, но меньше 16), причем оно может быть вещественным и может содержать всего 13 символов, включая точку.

Сначала пытался сделать посимвольным считыванием, не подключая доп.памяти, но сдался и ввел массив, который изначально заполнен числами -2. Функция transform должна считать все введенные символы и преобразовав их в числа записать в массив. Точка заменяется на число -1. Тут возникает первая проблема. Transform должна работать ровно столько раз, сколько было введено символов и не должна трогать другие ячейки массива. Но при вводе больших вещественных чисел ячейки массива в конце почему-то перезаписываются большими числами. Есть еще функция decimal, она переводит числа из любой системы счисления в десятичную. Но при выполнении программы она выводит многозначное число, не являющееся ответом. Помогите мне понять в чем проблема, я буду очень благодарен!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int counter = -1, i = -1, j = -1;

void transform(int* array_F)
{
    int x = getchar();
    if (x == '\n') return ;

    j++;
    if( x != '.')
    {
        if ((x - 'A') >= 0)
            array_F[j] = x - 'A' + 10;
        else
            array_F[j] = x - '0';
    }
    else array_F[j] = -1;
    transform(array_F);
}

void fractional(int first_ss, float* number_F, int* array_F)
{
    for(j = i+1; array_F[j]!= -2; j++) *number_F += (float)((array_F[j]) * pow(first_ss, -1*j));
}

void decimal(int first_ss, int* array_F, float* number_F)
{
    i++;
    if (array_F[i] == -2) return;

    if (array_F[i] == -1)
    {
        fractional(first_ss, number_F, array_F);
        return;
    }
    decimal(first_ss, array_F, number_F);
    counter++;
    *number_F += (float)(array_F[i - counter] * pow(first_ss, counter));
}
```

Comment: Если вы об этом:
 for(i = 0; i < j+8; i++)
    printf("%d",array[i]);
То я забыл удалить этот цикл. Он у меня для того, чтобы проверить значения массива.

Comment: А как что требуется делать, если результат бесконечен? Например, при переводе троичного `0.1` в десятичную систему результат `0.333...` бесконечен (периодичен). Просто урезать по длине (те же 13 символов)? Или искать период и использовать `()` нотацию?

Comment: Определите, пожалуйста, ограничения для входного набора данных.
Пока я предполагаю, что это цифры и заглавные латинские буквы. Так? В таком случае, я бы рекомендовал не изобретать велосипедов, а использовать isalnum(), isupper() и isdigit().

Answer (score 1):

Вы очень странным образом пытаетесь разделить функциональность между функциями. Если функция `transform()` должна производить промежуточное преобразование символов в числа, то незачем возлагать на неё также и функцию ввода данных. Со вводом строковых данных отлично справляется функция `scanf()`. Мало того, у неё есть и возможность выделять память под введённые строки (`%a`). Если не хочется вообще заниматься выделением памяти (даже и с помощью `scanf()`), то для посимвольной обработки функцию `getchar()` можно вызывать из внешней функции, передавая результат внутрь `transform()`. Оставьте функции `transform()` только свойственные ей действия.

Почему-то вместо того, чтобы при рекурсии в `decimal()` передавать параметром указатель на текущую позицию в обрабатываемом массиве, вы передаёте адрес начала массива, а указатель (точнее, индекс) идёт у вас в глобальной переменной. Да, собственно, и рекурсия-то в этом случае совершенно не нужна, а только расходует лишнее место на стеке.

Глобальные переменные - это зло. Data coupling между функциями должен быть нулевым, если нет жизненной необходимости. Неявные входные параметры функции - зло. Вся передача данных должна делаться через аргументы.
Иначе в будущем (при более серьёзном коде и большем масштабе проекта) неизбежны огромные проблемы класса "геморрой".

Мало того, в вашем коде эти проблемы присутствуют уже прямо сейчас, т.к. функция `transform()` работает исходя из предположения, что `j` на старте равна -1, однако, если кто-то вызовет `transform()` несколько раз, особенно после вызова `decimal()`->`fractional()`, то на входе в `tranform()` переменная `j` будет иметь мусорное значение.

При этом у вас НИГДЕ не контролируется выход за границы массива `Array_F`! Это гарантирует проблемы. Собственно это и предыдущее - вероятно и есть корень имеющихся у вас проблем. Кроме того, никак не обрабатываются печатные, но невалидные символы (пробелы, знаки препинания кроме точки, и т.д.).

Вообще не ясно, зачем нужна функция `decimal()`, если она фактически дополняет функциональность `transform()`. И вовсе не переводит в десятичную форму, а просто преобразует массив отдельных цифр произвольной системы счисления, созданный функцией `transform()` в обычное число типа `float`. Оно вовсе НЕ десятичное. Скорее уж двоичное в формате IEEE754. Логично было бы объединить все эти три функции в одну.

В целом, я бы полностью переделал этот код примерно так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>

double transform_char(double in, char c, int base, int fractional_position)
{
    int i;

    if(isalnum(c)) {
        if(isdigit(c)) {
            i = c - '0';
        }
        else if(isalpha(c)) {
            if(isupper(c)) {
                i = c - 'A' + 10;
            }
            else {
                i = c - 'a' + 10;
            }
        }

        if(i > base - 1) {
            return -NAN;
        }

        if(!fractional_position) {
            in *= base;
            in += i;
        }
        else {
            double frac = in - (int)in;
            in -= frac;
            frac += (double)i / pow(base, (double)fractional_position);
            in += frac;
        }
    }

    return in;
}
```

Эта функция обрабатывает строку посимвольно. Для целой части параметр `fractional_position` должен быть равен нулю. После обнаружения во входящем потоке символа точки, необходимо установить параметр в значение 1 и далее инкрементировать после каждого следующего обработанного символа:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

...

int input_base;
double res = 0.0;
char c = 0;
bool fraction = false;
int pos = 0;

... // Инициализация input_base где-то тут

while((c = getchar()) != '\n') {
    int i;

    printf("%c: %g -> ", c, res);

    if(isalnum(c)) {
        res = transform_char(res, c, input_base, pos);
        if(isnan(res)) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Invalid digit %c for base %d\n", c, input_base);
                break;
        }
        if(pos) pos++;
    }
    else if('.' == c) {
        fraction = true;
        pos = 1;
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid character %c\n", c);
        return 1;
    }

    printf("%g\n", res);
}
```

При этом обращаю ваше внимание на то, что обратное преобразование - задача более сложная. Хотя ваше ограничение в 13 символов её сильно облегчает. Решения изложены, например, вот тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228438/convert-double-float-to-string

Прошу также заметить, что мой код (как и ваш) не умеет обрабатывать отрицательные числа, но это легко исправить.