# Получить строку, содержащую десятичную запись числа

Tags: c, строки

Всем здравствуйте. Помогите с задачей. Строка содержит запись натурального числа в n-ричной системе счисления(n задается пользователем, 0 < n < 10). Получить строку содержащую десятичную запись этого числа

Comment: @Mike, я искал. Много, что перерыл. Я пытался сделать через оператор switch, но не выходит.

Comment: Вот например https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/578287/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%81-%D0%B2-%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%8E  это если вам нужен полностью ручной перевод без использования посторонних функций (этого в вопросы вы не указали). Заодно посмотрите как оформлен вопрос

Comment: :) k0 * n^0 + k1 * n^1 + k2 * n^2 ... , где k0,k1,k2 - цифры в  изначальном числе по порядку, n - база системы исчисления.  
  
325 в 8 ричной = 5*8^0 + 2*8^1 + 3*8^2 = 213 в десятичной  
это школьный курс информатики

Comment: Вы бы хоть у вопросе указали какими средствами это должно быть решено, потому что приведенный в ответе strtol полностью решает вашу задачу, остается только напечатать число с помощью pritnf();

Comment: @Mike Любыми средствами. Ну желательно с помощью библиотеки string. Я сейчас разбираюсь в тех вариантах, которые вы мне дали. Но это будет достаточно сложно. А вы имели ввиду strtok?

Comment: @Serg Если "любыми" средствами, то чем вам приведенный ответ не подходит ? вот рабочая программа даже на основе него https://ideone.com/oj36zy  строку берет, ответ выдает, что еще требуется ? А если все таки "руками", то вам задача максимально облегчена, в строке могут быть только цифры, раз n < 10, так что перевод букв даже не нужен

Comment: @Mike требуется во всем этом разобраться. И как-то на основе всего этого написать код. Буду пытаться делать. Спасибо за помощь, вы очень помогли.

Comment: Кстати, вот например исходники той самой strtol https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libiberty/strtol.c в общем там львиную долю можно выбросить. основная идея буквально в паре строк. очередную цифру из символов переводим в число. потом умножаем накапливаемый результат на основание системы счисления и прибавляем цифру. собственно все. правда мы получаем машинное представление результата. дальше либо используем printf, который сам сделает из него десятичную систему, либо делаем сами последовательно выводя остатки от деления на 10 (в обратном порядке), например

Comment: @Mike Я сделал с помощью функции itoa.

Answer (score 2):

Ну что такое запись в системе счисления по основанию n? это

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

т.е. значение многочлена, которое можно просто посчитать по схеме Горнера:

```
char s[] = "14614235462";  // у вас n < 10 - так что только цифры...
int n = 7; // Основание системы счисления

int val = 0;
for(*c = s; *c; ++*c)
{
    int digit = *c - '0';            // Значение очередной цифры
    assert(digit >= 0 && digit < n); // Убедиться, что верная цифра
    val = val*n+ digit;
}

char out[20];
snprintf(out,"%d",val);
```

Все, в строке `out` - десятичная запись исходного числа

Answer (score 1):

Если нужна готовая функция то вот например:

```
int main()
{
    const char* str = "1234";
    int n = ::strtol(str,NULL, 10);

    const char* str2 = "A";
    int n2 = ::strtol(str2, NULL, 16);

    return 0;
}
```